# Django: How to specify custom media directory for JQuery lightbox plugin?

Tags: jquery, django

I'm trying to use the jQuery LighBox plugin in my Django app, by the Javascript appears to generate HTML to hard-coded image paths (e.g. images/loading.gif). How do I customize these image paths so they point to my Media directory?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is not "*media*", rather "*static*" files. "*media*" is aimed at serving user images etc., while "*static*" is designed to contain static content (such as CSS styles, JS scripts, images used by CSS, logo etc.).

Detailed guide is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Basically you need to put static files of lightbox interface somewhere in `/static/` directory within your Django app. During deployment you will need to collect static files to the separate directory using [`collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) management command.

If you will use `{{ STATIC_URL }}` within template, the paths will be generated correctly (`STATIC_URL` within templates having request context contains the URL of your static files directory). Just make sure you use proper settings for static files (mostly [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATIC_URL) and [`STATIC_DIR`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATIC_ROOT), details are under the link I have given).